# How to insert fields to different tables at once?

Tags: mysql

5 Main Tables: TEMP, PAYMENT, CUSTOMER, PURCHASE, and PRODUCT.

- TEMP:     TempID, Email, Name, Product1, Product2, Date, Amount
- PAYMENT:  PaymentID, Status, Amount, Date
- CUSTOMER: CustomerID, Email, Name
- PURCHASE: CustomerID, PaymentID, ProductID, Quantity
- PRODUCT:  ProductID, ProductName, Price

How to insert each field from TEMP where TEMP.Email = '$Email' to PAYMENT, CUSTOMER, PURCHASE, and PRODUCT:

- TEMP.Email    >> CUSTOMER.Email
- TEMP.Name     >> CUSTOMER.Name
- TEMP.Product1 >> PURCHASE.ProductID
- TEMP.Product2 >> PURCHASE.ProductID
- TEMP.Date     >> PAYMENT.Date
- TEMP.Amount   >> PAYMENT.Amount

Answer (score 3):

You could write an (AFTER?) INSERT trigger, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER temp_inserts_trg AFTER INSERT ON temp
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO customer VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.Email, NEW.Name);
        INSERT INTO payment...
        ...
    END;
```

Check the [MySQL CREATE TRIGGER documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for more info.